# Are there Corda examples/documentation demonstrating the "validating notary"?

Tags: corda

I have build a CorDapp using "Yo!CorDapp" example (https://github.com/corda/spring-observable-stream), over release-v1 of Corda platform.

The CorDapp has four nodes - Controller node (provides network map service and validating notary service), "node A", "node B" and "node C". Following are the flows defined in the app -

Flow 1: "Node A" sends a trade request to "Node B". "Node C" is also notified.

Flow 2: "Node B" approves the trade request, self-signs it, gets signature from A and closes the trade. "Node C" is also notified.

The CorDapps needs implementation of a validating notary to enforce accountability.

Are there any examples/documentation in git/elsewhere that demonstrates the implementation aspect of the validating notary?

If yes, please provide links to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the line **advertisedServices = ["corda.notary.validating"]** in the deployNodes section (see below) of build.gradle for the Controller node, we can implement a validating notary.

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
  directory "./build/nodes"
  networkMap "O=Controller,L=London,C=GB"
  node {
      name "O=Controller,L=London,C=GB"
      advertisedServices = ["corda.notary.validating"]
      p2pPort 10002
      rpcPort 10003
      cordapps = ["com.bgc:bgc:1"]
  }
```